# Conditional Probability of Being the Last Name Drawn in a Raffle.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

There is a raffle with 306 entries. One name (Billy) is entered 48 times and other 258 entries are unique. Names are drawn and not replaced until only 1 name is left.

What is the probability that Billy will be the last name to be drawn?

What is the probability that Billy will be one of the last 5 names to be drawn?

Comment: When you say "until only $1$ name is left", do you mean "until only one ticket is left", or "until all the remaining tickets have the same name on them"?
When you say "one of the last $5$ names", do you mean exactly one, or at least one?
What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?